# Creating an observation number dependent on date and time variables

Tags: datetime, time-series, spss, mixed-models

I have a database with 100 participants, identified by the variable 'id'. The database also includes a 'StartDate' variable indicating the date and time each participant took the survey in the format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss'. There are two observations per day.

I want to create a new variable called 'observation' that indicates the number of observations for each participant according to the date variable.

Each participant can have up to 40 observations. 2 observations per day (morning and evening).
If there are two surveys on the same date, the number of observations is still +1.
If there are two observations on the same day, and then a day is skipped - it is 1,2,5.

For example - 11.10.2023 23:08:13 (skipped morning), 12.10.2023 22:01:12 (skipped morning), 13.10.2023 20:14:17 (skipped morning), 14.10.2023 10:30:18, 14.10.2023 19:45:18 the 'observation' variable should take the values 2, 4, 6, 7, and 8 respectively.

How can I write an SPSS syntax to create the observation variable?

Comment: Does anything change if the evening observation was skipped instead of morning? If so how do you determine if an observation is morning or evening?

Comment: @eli-k It should use the same logic as when skipping the morning survey. E.g. 11.10.2023 23:08:13 (skipped morning), 12.10.2023 10:01:12 (skipped evening), 13.10.2023 20:14:17 (skipped morning), 14.10.2023 10:30:18, 14.10.2023 19:45:18 the 'observation' variable should take the values 2, 3, 6, 7, and 8 respectively. Morning and evening is determined by the hour. Morning 6:00-12:00. Evening 18:00-24:00

Comment: +1 for nice question, but please edit it for better readability (examples + expected results should be in a table rather then text paragraph) of future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax calculates the number of days passed between each observation and the first observation for that ID. Each passed day is worth +2 in the observation count, and then +1 for morning and +2 for evening observation.
The syntax assumes your original date-time variable is stored as text:

```
compute YourDate=number(YourTextDT, DATE8).
FORMATS YourDate (DATE9) .
compute evening=number(char.substr(YourTextDT,12,2),f2)>=18.
aggregate outfile=* mode=addvariables /break ID/mindate=min(YourDate).
compute observation=datediff(YourDate, mindate, "days")*2+1+evening.
execute.
```